# ASP.Net MVC 4 and JavaScript frameworks with - AJAX and Unobtrusive validation

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, single-page-application

In asp.net MVC (not WebAPI), we can make asynchronous requests to controller using  **AJAX** and jQuery. I have made bunch of functions to call the controllers where required.
For Validation, we can take the advantage of **DataAnnotation validation of Model** and use **unobtrusive validation**.

But on seeing the recent javascript frameworks like, backbone, knockout and many other,

Is there any best way to use these frameworks for the asp.net MVC application.

I inspired using of Javascript architectures [here](http://www.johnpapa.net/spa), which is wonderful introduction to **ASP.NET MVC SPAs**.

I also read alot of blogs about **backbone** usage and **knockout** observables (MVVM), but cant find the way to stick them all together. The advantages would be ease of maintaining javascript.

I have seen the **Todomvc** application (selecting MV*), and can see the best use of model, but not validations and ajax.

On concluding,
   What is the best way to use the existing **JavaScript frameworks** in ASP.NET MVC4 application (not WebAPI) for **AJAX, unobtrusive validation** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this Microsoft article [ASP.Net Single Package Application](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application) and make your choice depending on what you want.

I think that Breeze/Knockout template is the best choice for the simple and small or medium size applications - it is the fastest and easiest way for ASP.Net MVC integration.

But for the large (reach) applications the Breeze/Angular or DurandalJS templates would be better choice.

Answer (score 1):

For KnockoutJS there is [KnockoutMVC](http://knockoutmvc.com/Home/Introduction) library exists. It helps with building view models and many other things.

Comment: Hi STO, thanks for your answer, I have seen KnockoutMVC. All we have in knockout is binding observables and iterating the collections. But I want how make ajax calls with these models and also validations from the Emdx DataModel (unobtrusive validation).